# what kind of data can we extract from a blog or a forum for a web scraping project?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

I am about to work on a project about 'analysing data from blog or forum' so I am wondering what kind of data can we extract from a blog or a forum and how should I get started

Comment: Your question could be interesting but it is very vague about specifics. Is this about one blog in particular or all blogs in general? Are you looking for a toolset or an existing project? Maybe start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping ?

Comment: I'm talking about any blog in general and looking for a toolset, thank you

Comment: You are solving the problem in exactly opposite direction. Instead of looking for some kind of data, fix what is it that you want to learn about. Then collect the required data from the blogs for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should decide which programming language to use. Then, you should consider using a web scraper.

There are different ones for different programming languages. For Java, there is [jsoup](https://jsoup.org) for example.

As to what data can be obtained you have to first consider the format of the page. But data that I would recommend collecting consists of:

Usernames
Photos on the site
Data related to usernames (Join date, Number of posts, Premium member status, Photo, Phone numbers, E-mail addresses, Full name, address, etc. (if applicable)), 
Title of blog posts, 
Questions asked on forums, 
Number of answers for each question, 
Typos in the blog post, 
Date related info.